# Highcharts Error: chart.yAxis, chart.series, this.options is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, typeerror

Hey I keep getting this problem, I'm still a complete beginner regarding programmation so it could just be that I forgot to include something really important in the code, but when first generating a chart on my website the chart has no problem generating and show9ing a trendline and min/max values, but when changing the date none of those features work and I get these error messages that the different elements are undefined.
Here is my javascript function:

```
  //------------------------------------------Load Chart and Data------------------------------------------
    function loadData(startDate, endDate) {
      var startIndex = dateData.indexOf(startDate);
      var endIndex = dateData.indexOf(endDate);

      var selectedDates = dateData.slice(endIndex, startIndex + 1);
      var selectedSales = salesData.slice(endIndex, startIndex + 1);

      var promises = [];
      var weatherData = [];
      console.log(weatherData);

      selectedDates.forEach(function (date) {
        var requestUrl = `https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=49.97&longitude=5.93&daily=weathercode,temperature_2m_max&current_weather=true&forecast_days=1&start_date=${date}&end_date=${date}&timezone=Europe%2FBerlin`;

        promises.push(
          $.ajax({
            url: requestUrl,
            dataType: 'json'
          }).done(function (data) {
            console.log('Weather API response received');

            var weather = data?.daily?.weathercode[0];
            var iconURL = getWeatherIcon(weather);
            var temp = data?.daily?.temperature_2m_max[0];

            weatherData.push({
              date: date,
              weather: weather,
              temperature: temp,
              iconURL: iconURL
            });
          }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('AJAX request failed:', textStatus, errorThrown);
            weatherData.push({
              date: date,
              weather: undefined,
              temperature: undefined,
              iconURL: undefined
            });
          })
        );
      });

      //------------------------------------------Generate Basic Chart------------------------------------------
      $.when.apply($, promises).done(function () {
        console.log('All AJAX requests completed');

        var chartData = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < selectedSales.length; i++) {
          var sales = selectedSales[i];
          var currentDate = selectedDates[i];
          var weatherDataItem = weatherData.find(data => data.date === currentDate);
          var weather = weatherDataItem?.weather;
          var temperature = weatherDataItem?.temperature;
          var iconURL = weatherDataItem?.iconURL;

          var pointIndex = selectedSales.length - i - 1;

          let symbolURL = iconURL;
          let symbolWidth = 32;
          let symbolHeight = 32;

          chartData.push({
            x: Date.parse(selectedDates[i]),
            y: sales,
            weather: weather,
            temperature: temperature,
            marker: {
              symbol: 'url(' + symbolURL + ')',
              width: symbolWidth,
              height: symbolHeight,
            },
            events: {
              click: function () {
                console.log('Data point clicked:', this);
              }
            },
            plotLines: []
          });
        }

        var chartOptions = {
          title: {
            text: 'Sales Chart'
          },
          xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            title: {
              text: 'Date'
            }
          },
          yAxis: {
            title: {
              text: 'Sales'
            }
          },
          tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
              return (
                '<b>Date:</b> ' +
                Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', this.x) +
                '<br>' +
                '<b>Sales:</b> ' +
                this.y + '€' +
                '<br>' +
                '<b>Temperature:</b> ' +
                this.point.temperature +
                '°C'
              );
            }
          },
          series: [
            {
              name: 'Sales',
              data: chartData,
              zIndex: 1
            }
          ]
        };

        if (this.chart) {
          // Check if a chart already exists
          var existingSeries = this.chart.series[0];
          console.log(this.chart.series[0]);
          existingSeries.setData(chartData); // Update the existing series with new data

          // Remove other series if needed
          for (let i = 1; i < this.chart.series.length; i++) {
            this.chart.series[i].remove();
          }

          // Recalculate trendline
          calculateTrendline(chartData, this.chart);
        } else {
          // Generate a new chart
          var chart = Highcharts.chart('chart', chartOptions);
        }

        loadStats(selectedDates, selectedSales, weatherData);

        //------------------------------------------Generate Trendline------------------------------------------
        let trendlineSeries = null;

        function calculateTrendline(data, chart)
        {
          var n = data.length;
          let sumX = 0;
          let sumY = 0;
          let sumXY = 0;
          let sumXX = 0;

          for (let i = 0; i < n; i++)
          {
            const point = data[i];
            const x = point.x;
            const y = point.y;

            sumX += x;
            if(y > 0)
            {
              sumY += y;
              sumXY += x * y;
            }
            sumXX += x * x;
          }

          var slope = (n * sumXY - sumX * sumY) / (n * sumXX - sumX * sumX);
          var intercept = (sumY - slope * sumX) / n;

          var trendline = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            var point = data[i];
            var x = point.x;
            var y = slope * x + intercept;

            trendline.push([x, y]);
          }

          if (trendlineSeries) {
            trendlineSeries.remove();
            trendlineSeries = null; // Reset the variable
          }

          trendlineSeries = chart.addSeries({
            name: 'Trendline',
            type: 'line',
            data: trendline,
            color: '#C57AFA',
            zIndex: 1
          });
        }
        //------------------------------------------Generate Trendline------------------------------------------

        //------------------------------------------Show and hide Trendline------------------------------------------
        var chart = Highcharts.chart('chart', chartOptions);

        $("#trendlineCheckbox").on("change", function () {
          var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
          if (checked) {
            calculateTrendline(chartData, chart);
          } else {
            if (trendlineSeries) {
              trendlineSeries.remove();
            }
          }
        });

        //------------------------------------------Show and hide Trendline------------------------------------------

        //------------------------------------------Show and Hide Weather Icons------------------------------------------
        $("#weatherIconsCheckbox").on("change", function () {
          var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
          if (checked && chart) {
            chart.series[0].update({
              marker: {
                enabled: true
              }
            });
          } else if (chart) {
            chart.series[0].update({
              marker: {
                enabled: false
              }
            });
          }
        });

        //------------------------------------------Show and Hide Weather Icons------------------------------------------

        //------------------------------------------Show and Hide Minimum and Maximum------------------------------------------
        $("#minimumCheckbox, #maximumCheckbox").on("change", function () {
          var minimumChecked = $("#minimumCheckbox").is(":checked");
          var maximumChecked = $("#maximumCheckbox").is(":checked");

          // Filter out invalid or empty values from selectedSales
          const filteredSales = selectedSales.filter(sale => !isNaN(sale));

          // Calculate minimum and maximum values from the filtered array
          const minValue = Math.min(...filteredSales);
          const maxValue = Math.max(...filteredSales);

          // Remove the plot lines if the corresponding checkbox is unchecked
          if (!minimumChecked) {
            chart.yAxis[0].removePlotLine('minimum');
          }
          if (!maximumChecked) {
            chart.yAxis[0].removePlotLine('maximum');
          }

          // Add the plot lines if the corresponding checkbox is checked
          if (minimumChecked) {
            chart.yAxis[0].addPlotLine({
              value: minValue,
              width: 2,
              color: '#5354E5',
              id: 'minimum',
              label: {
                text: 'Minimum',
                align: 'center',
                style: {
                  color: '#5354E5'
                }
              }
            });
          }
          if (maximumChecked) {
            chart.yAxis[0].addPlotLine({
              value: maxValue,
              width: 2,
              color: '#FF5636',
              id: 'maximum',
              label: {
                text: 'Maximum',
                align: 'center',
                style: {
                  color: '#FF5636'
                }
              }
            });
          }

          chart.redraw();
        });
        //------------------------------------------Show and Hide Minimum and Maximum------------------------------------------

      });
    }
```

I tried to see with some console.logs to see if the code enters the functions correctly but without any success, I want the chart to always be able to show/hide the trendline based on the current data chosen and min/max value of the currently chosen data. Here is a JSFiddle with the code if you want to try for yourself or maybe get a better idea of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/MikeList/8gyd0xtL/2/

Comment: Hi @Mike List, I have limited possibilities to investigate your code, so it would be best if you could create a live example of the functionality. However, it seems that your `chart` variable has a different scope than you expect, please try to move the variable outside of the `loadData` function and refer to it without `this`. Code: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/02zrt3dg/

Comment: Hey thank you for the reply, the thing is that right now I currently already have the variable chart outside of the function and replaced the ths.chart, but I still keep getting the error. I put the code here in this JSFiddle, maybe you find something I did completely wrong in the code
https://jsfiddle.net/MikeList/8gyd0xtL/2/

Comment: There must be something wrong with the `chart` variable. I can't be sure without running the code, but here: `var chart = Highcharts.chart('chart', chartOptions);` you are creating a new variable and you probably want to assign a new value only, so use: `chart = Highcharts.chart('chart', chartOptions);`.